# Unable to use Matplotlib with Raspberry PI4

Tags: python, matplotlib, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to use Python on my PI4. I have a very simple program:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.array([1, 3, 4, 6])
y = np.array([2, 3, 5, 1])
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

I have install matplotlib with:

```sh
sudo apt install python3-matplotlib
```

I use IDLE shell 3.9.2 and I have the following error:

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xf but this version of numpy is 0xd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Python/Test01.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 109, in <module>
    from . import _api, _version, cbook, docstring, rcsetup
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/matplotlib/rcsetup.py", line 27, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, is_color_like
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/matplotlib/colors.py", line 56, in <module>
    from matplotlib import _api, cbook, scale
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/matplotlib/scale.py", line 23, in <module>
    from matplotlib.ticker import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/matplotlib/ticker.py", line 136, in <module>
    from matplotlib import transforms as mtransforms
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 46, in <module>
    from matplotlib._path import (
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

I can't solve that!!

Comment: What version of `numpy` do you have installed? Check with `pip freeze` or `pip3 freeze`.

Comment: How did you install NumPy? The solution might be `sudo apt install python3-numpy`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What have you already tried? I don't want to repeat something if you've already tried it.

Comment: Did you try googling the RuntimeError? I found a bunch of possibly helpful results.

Comment: My version of numpy is 1.19.5.

Comment: Now I have 1.22.1, and the problem is still here :-(

Comment: I have add: PATH=$PATH:/home/pi/.local/bin, and after a restart, it's working!

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue but finally figured out a solution!
Here's what I did:

1. Type the following in the terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt remove python3-numpy
   sudo apt install libatlas3-base
   ```

   In removing numpy, other files and directories will also be removed,
   including matplotlib.
2. If using Thonny IDE, select 'Tools' -> 'Manage packages...'
3. In the search bar of the new window, type *numpy*, then click 'Search on PyPI'
4. Click on the first search result to install!